# php sessions and cookie lifetime

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime",10);
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["BAN"])){
echo "<font color='red'>you can no longer          login for this session,<font     color='blue'>please restart your browser</    font></font>";
}else{
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name=$_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["FAIL"];
if($name!="emmy"){
$_SESSION["FAIL"]++;
echo "<font color='red'>wrong     password...try again </font><br>";
//echo "wrong by ".$_SESSION["FAIL"]." time(s)<br>";
}else{
echo "access granted....
<br> ";
}
if($_SESSION["FAIL"]>3){
$_SESSION["BAN"]="bad";
echo "you
 entered the wrong password too many     times";
//header("location:pat.php");
}
}
echo <<< DOC
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text"name="name"/>
<input type="submit"name="submit"/>
</form>
DOC;
}
?>
```

The above code is supposed to restrict login access after failed attempts more than 3,but the cookie lifetime isn't applying and when I run the code ,it runs fine but an error is generated at first run....please check the code and help...

Comment: what is the error you're getting?  and OMG a `font` tag *covers eyes*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init the `$_SESSION["FAIL"]` so do when you add 1 to the variable

```
if(isset($_SESSION["FAIL"])) {
    $_SESSION["FAIL"]++;
} else {
    $_SESSION["FAIL"] = 1;
}
```

so only for you

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime",10);
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["BAN"])){
echo "<font color='red'>you can no longer          login for this session,<font     color='blue'>please restart your browser</    font></font>";
}else{
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name=$_POST["name"];
if($name!="emmy"){
if(isset($_SESSION["FAIL"])) {
    $_SESSION["FAIL"]++;
} else {
    $_SESSION["FAIL"] = 1;
}
echo "<font color='red'>wrong     password...try again </font><br>";
//echo "wrong by ".$_SESSION["FAIL"]." time(s)<br>";
}else{
echo "access granted....
<br> ";
}
if(isset($_SESSION["FAIL"]) && $_SESSION["FAIL"]>3){
$_SESSION["BAN"]="bad";
echo "you
 entered the wrong password too many     times";
//header("location:pat.php");
}
}
echo <<< DOC
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text"name="name"/>
<input type="submit"name="submit"/>
</form>
DOC;
}
?>
```

Comment: OK tanx ..but why won't the cookie lifetime run or is it cuz my server is the one on android??

Comment: Please I ran the code but when I first enter an incorrect password, it says undefined index "fail" on line 9 and 11 ....

Comment: @IorzuaEmmanuel where did you add this? remove the $_SESSION["FAIL"] in line 9 because its useless the one on line 11 you should replace with my code

Comment: if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name=$_POST["name"];
if($name!="emmy"){
$_SESSION["FAIL"]++;
echo "<font color='red'>wrong password...try again </font><br>";
//echo "wrong by ".$_SESSION["FAIL"]." time(s)<br>";
}else{
$_SESSION["FAIL"]=1;
echo "access granted....
<br> ";
}

Comment: why you posting that?

Comment: That's the new code ..is that how its supposed to be??